# How to get a total number of rows in database table along with some rows using PostgreSQL function (to select with Dapper)?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, dapper, sql-function

I need to get a filtered set of rows from the PostgreSQL table along with a total number of records there.
Previously I was writing raw SQL queries and all flow looked like this (taken from another answer):

```
var sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books;
            SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY bookID OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY";

using(var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
{
    var count = multi.Read<int>().Single();
    var results = multi.Read<YourObject>().ToList();
}
```

But we switched to PostgreSQL functions and now I need to get the same result with them. How is it possible?

1. Should I just make another procedure and query it to get total values (seems inefficient)?
2. Should I put multiple SELECT statements inside one function (but I don't need the same total value for each row of the results table)?

Are there other options?

**UPDATE**

Code above is an example of how I was working with this stuff. Now I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_books(offset_value integer, fetch_value integer)
RETURNS TABLE("BookId" uuid, "BookName" varchar)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT 
  id AS BookId,
  book_name AS BookName
FROM books
OFFSET offset_value ROWS FETCH NEXT fetch_value ROWS ONLY;
$function$
;
```

And C# code:

```
var result = await connection.QueryAsync<BookDto>("get_books", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

It works but I also need a total number of rows in my *books* table.

Comment: I think you need to add a ; after the first select also.

Comment: @PalleDue it's just an example. I'm not using it anymore

Comment: Add a Count to the Select : SELECT *,Count(add item here).  Even though you have an asterisks you can add additional values.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know that there would be any advantage of this, performance or otherwise, but you *could* combine the two into one query using the `count` analytic function:

```
select
  count (*) over (partition by 1), *
from books
limit 10
```

Your object would have to account for the additional field, and it would repeat on every record.  For small datasets, who cares, but if you are storing a million list items then that's storing the same value one extra million times.

I actually think your original approach is preferred, as it retains the count in a scalar, but offering this as an idea.